# Method signature through call stack introspection

Tags: java

Is there any way of finding the signature of a called method through call stack introspection. Do we have any alternatives for finding out the same. I do not have the source code and have only bytecode files

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This was answered in a similar question (valid for Java 10+). In brief: this IS possible but  you have to use StackWalker instead of StackTraceElement: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72492273/7249306

Comment: @DenisAbakumov Ofcourse and Java 10 did not exist 10 years back ;)

Comment: Sanyam, of course, people are coming to SO to find answers to questions that were asked many years ago, maybe before some of them were born :-). Does this mean they shouldn't get answers based on current state of the industry? I just left my comment in a place where such people are most likely to find it. But you're 100% right in your note.

Comment: @DenisAbakumov Yes correct, Probably we should start adding versions with questions and answers too, it could lead to some using old apis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stack introspection will give you the caller of the method or at best few details of the method, for exact method signature you will have to use reflection.

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
```

> Official documentation says:
>
> Returns an array of stack trace elements representing the stack dump
>   of this thread. This method will return a zero-length array if this
>   thread has not started or has terminated. If the returned array is of
>   non-zero length then the first element of the array represents the top
>   of the stack, which is the most recent method invocation in the
>   sequence. The last element of the array represents the bottom of the
>   stack, which is the least recent method invocation in the sequence.

This way from [StackTrace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html) you can get the method name, filename, linenumber.

For complete method signature you will have to use reflection

Comment: Yes reflection is indeed helpful in finding the signature but my requirement is that I have to find the signature of method obtained from call stack introspection and I do not have source code How would I know which method ( say some overloaded method) was called using call stack and reflection without using source code I do have byte codes though??

Comment: i do not think you can, afaik only method name and (if available debug -g) line number are present in stack trace. If its one time solution try decompile class and check line number

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Java Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) and [StackTraceElement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html) .

```
StackTraceElement[] elements = new Throwable().getStackTrace();

    String calleeMethod = elements[0].getMethodName();
    String callerMethodName = elements[1].getMethodName();
    String callerClassName = elements[1].getClassName();

    System.out.println("CallerClassName=" + callerClassName + " , Caller method name: " + callerMethodName);
    System.out.println("Callee method name: " + calleeMethod);
```

Comment: I think your post is in no way helpful to my question

Comment: This doesn't answer the principal question: how to get method *signature*, i.e. its parameters and their types.

Answer (score 0):

The StackTraceElement does not contain any information about the parameters, so if you have multiple methods in the calling class with the same name and you want to know which one, you will need access to the source. In the case of the original question, you could try recreating the sources with a decompiler, compile from those sources, then recreate the stack trace and look at the line number in the recreated sources.

If overloaded methods are not a concern, this is what you can do:

```
public class TestTest {
    @Test
    public void overloaded1() throws Exception {
        doTheThing("foo", 42, this);
    }

    @Test
    public void overloaded2() throws Exception {
        doTheThing(1);
    }

    @Test
    public void notOverloaded() throws Exception {
        printMethodSignature();
    }

    public void doTheThing(int overloaded) throws Exception {
        printMethodSignature();
    }

    public void doTheThing(String dumm1, int dummy2, Object dummy3) throws Exception {
        printMethodSignature();
    }

    public void printMethodSignature() throws Exception {
        StackTraceElement[] elements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        // elements[0] will contain java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace() here
        // elements[1] will contain this method: printMethodSignature()
        // elements[2] will contain the method from which printMethodSignature() was called

        System.out.println(elements[2] + " -> " + toSignature(elements[2]));
    }

    // Represent class & method as string
    public String toSignature(StackTraceElement st) throws Exception {
        Class callingClass = Class.forName(st.getClassName());
        return Stream.of(callingClass.getMethods())
            .filter(m -> m.getName().equals(st.getMethodName()))
            .map(m -> String.format("%s.%s(%s)", callingClass.getName(), m.getName(), toSignature(m)))
            .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
    }

    // Represent parameters as a String
    public String toSignature(Method method) {
        return Stream.of(method.getParameters())
            .map(p -> p.getParameterizedType().getTypeName())
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
    }
}
```