# Ignore calls from a certain method inside obfuscated code

Tags: java, obfuscation, stack-trace, minecraft

I am trying to find the method signature of the caller method.  I need to do this because the code I'm writing gets obfuscated and a  lot of methods get overloaded. I'm trying to ignore calls from a certain method that has the signature At the moment my code looks like this

```
StackTraceElement caller = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2];
String cn = caller.getClassName();
String mn = caller.getMethodName();
if(cn == "net.minecraft.client.Minecraft" && (mn == "displayGuiScreen" || mn == "a")){ // displayGuiScreen is for non-obfuscated, a is for obfuscated. Doesn't work because 2 other methods that call it are also called a when obfuscated
    System.err.println("Skipped");
    return;
}
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945118/method-signature-through-call-stack-introspection

Comment: This question seems to be doing exactly what the linked answer suggests. This question explains that the problem is complicated by obfuscation. The name of the method in the obfuscated stack trace is now ambiguous.

Comment: Does `getLineNumber()` return separate values for the different overloads of `a()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [asm library](http://asm.ow2.org/), and I've just found I think related to you post, try to read and find out example, [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024587/get-callers-method-java-lang-reflect-method)

Comment: I'm trying to keep this as small as possible because it's a mod, so I'd rather not use a whole new library.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use AspectJ with compile-time weaving. You can use [around advice](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/semantics-advice.html) to do nothing if the caller is the displayGuiScreen method. This will only work if you compile all the code that calls your class. Compile-time weaving is necessary because you must do it before obfuscation and for all callers of your method. You should be able to do something like this:

```
aspect IgnoreCallsFromDisplayGuiScreen {
    void around(): call(void MyClass.myMethod()) && withincode(void Minecraft.displayGuiScreen()) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First verify that your code works without obfuscation.

Second, find the obfuscation map, which is an output of the obfuscation program.

Third verify that your obfuscator updated the string to match the new method signature as it is detailed in the map.  Odds are only the class name and method names have changed.

If you do not have a match, either look to your obfuscator for an option to rewrite strings that look like reflection calls, or use asm to rewrite the string within the compiled class that didn't get the update.

Comment: I know what it is obfuscated to (`a`), as stated in the code. I also know the method signature (GuiScreen). The problem is getting the method signature to compare it!