# How to get method signature (not method name) from Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()?

Tags: java, methods, stack-trace

Suppose I have the following methods and their invocations:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {zoo();}
public static void zoo() {zoo(0);}
public static void zoo(int i) {too(i);}
public static void too(int i) {...}
```

`Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` will return me with something like:

```
A.too(A.java:56)
A.zoo(A.java:65)
A.zoo(A.java:60)
A.main(A.java:80)
```

With this output, I cannot distinguish the 2 `zoo`s I defined in my example, one without any parameter (`zoo()`) and one with an integer parameter (`zoo(int i)`). The reason is because only method names rather than their signatures are outputted. Is there a way to get a stack of method signatures?

Comment: If you have a look at  `StackTraceElement` you'll only see `methodName` among other fields. So you can't get the signature out of this. Why exactly do you need this? Using the line number to look into the appropriate source file should already help (unless source and compiled version don't match anymore - but there are other ways to tackle that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of the [StackTraceElement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html#toString()) in Java 13 clearly shows that there is no way to do that. You can identify the overloaded method by its line number with your human brain. Automatizing this task would be overkill if even possible (would require using *hard* reflection), although I do not close out that some lib can do that.

Remark: the binary file format of the .class files actually [has the method signature information](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html) (at least the parameter list), thus it is not impossible, only no one developed it until now.

Answer (score 2):

You can not get the method signature from a [`StackTraceElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html), but since you’re interested in getting the stack trace of the [currentThread](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#currentThread()), you can use [`StackWalker`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StackWalker.html) instead. Since Java 10, it supports [getting the method type](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StackWalker.StackFrame.html#getMethodType()) from a [`StackFrame`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StackWalker.StackFrame.html).

For example

```java
public class StackWalkerExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        zoo();
        System.out.println();
        Arrays.asList("foo", "bar").sort((a, b) -> { getMethods(); return 0; });
    }

    public static void zoo() {zoo(0);}
    public static void zoo(int i) {too(i);}
    public static void too(int i) { getMethods(); }

    static void getMethods() {
        var sw = StackWalker.getInstance(StackWalker.Option.RETAIN_CLASS_REFERENCE);
        var methods = sw.walk(frames ->
            frames.skip(1).map(StackWalkerExample::toMethod).toArray(Method[]::new));

        for(var m: methods) System.out.println(m);
    }

    static Method toMethod(StackWalker.StackFrame f) {
        try {
            return f.getDeclaringClass().getDeclaredMethod(
                    f.getMethodName(), f.getMethodType().parameterArray());
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }
}
```

will print

```
public static void StackWalkerExample.too(int)
public static void StackWalkerExample.zoo(int)
public static void StackWalkerExample.zoo()
public static void StackWalkerExample.main(java.lang.String[])

private static int StackWalkerExample.lambda$0(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
private static int java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(java.lang.Object[],int,int,java.util.Comparator)
static void java.util.TimSort.sort(java.lang.Object[],int,int,java.util.Comparator,java.lang.Object[],int,int)
public static void java.util.Arrays.sort(java.lang.Object[],java.util.Comparator)
public void java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.sort(java.util.Comparator)
public static void StackWalkerExample.main(java.lang.String[])
```

<sup>Details of the sorting implementation may vary</sup>